# Two disks on MAC (one physical, the other virtual)

Tags: mac, partitioning

This is the "diskutil list" output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +249.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 6C4DC6E1-CAC4-4A2A-8A43-6C569C6C21BE
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

I don't understand why I have two disks. One physical and other virtual. Could someone explain?. Thanks

Comment: /dev/disk0 (internal, physical)   and /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):

Answer (score 0):

`disk0s2` is an encrypted partition managed by CoreStorage.

CoreStorage presents it to the system as the virtual volume `disk1s0`.

When the rest of the system reads and writes `disk1s0`, CoreStorage takes care of [de|en]crypting on the way to/from the physical volume `disk0s2`